# How to get details of a remote host within the local network in Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I want to get details of all my network hosts in my LAN. I managed to get Hostname and Mac-Address already (via ARP), but I need more details like Vendor name and other details. There are Port scanning tools which can achieve this.

Also Windows 7 lists these details of network devices, e.g. for my TV it lists Samsung as vendor, serial number and even model number. For my android device it says LG Electronics as vendor.

How can I scan this information with java and what type of information is this? Is it NetBIOS?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to use UPnP for some of this.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have java example code how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Scanning network devices to glean information from them is an entire security topic in and of itself and so I won't attempt to cover it all. It also depends on how far you want to go.

If you just want the vendor information, for example, then you can take the MAC Address you gleaned from ARP and look up the prefix bits against a list of vendors that own them. Wireshark have what appears to be a pretty complete list of MAC address prefixes to vendors [here](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/wireshark/trunk/manuf).

Further than that I would suggest you outsource the hard work of writing device fingering tools yourself and utilize an application like [NMap](http://nmap.org/) to do it all for you. NMap, I believe, has a commandline option and so you simply need to call it from Java and parse in the results.

Comment: No problems mate. Please upvote and tick the answer as correct if its what you were looking for. :)